# Completion of a Banach space with respect to a different norm

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $(X,|\cdot|_X)$ be a Banach space. Define a space $Y$ as the completion of $X$ under a norm
$$|u|_Y = |u|_X + |Tu|_Z$$
where $T:X \to Z$ is a linear continuous map where $X \subset Z$ is a continuous embedding.

What can I say about this new space $Y$? Is it true that: if $v \notin X$, and if the $Y$-norm of $v$ is finite, then $v \in Y?$

Comment: If $v \not\in X$, and it is not known that $v \in Y$, then what does 
"the $Y$-norm of $v$" even mean?

Comment: Sorry I made a misstake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T$ is continuous, we have $|Tu|_Z\leq c|u|_X.$ Hence $$|u|_X\leq|u|_Y\leq |u|_X(1+c),$$ i.e. the norms $|\cdot|_X,|\cdot|_Y$ are equivalent. Thus the completion of $X$ w.r.t. $|\cdot|_Y$ is canonically isomorphic to $X.$